# Implement a function reverse strings(my list) that takes a list of strings, and returns the strings concatenated in reverse order

Tags: python, list

```
def reverse_strings(my_list):
    new_string=""
    for x in my_list:
        new_string=new_string+my_list[-1]
        my_list.pop()
    return new_string
```

it does  not add the first object of the list in the new string and we can not use the reverse function

Comment: It's not clear if the list should be reversed or each string should be reversed. Can you post example input and desired output?

Comment: If you just want to reverse the list, `''.join(l[::-1])`

Answer (score 0):

The issue if you're modifying/popping the same list you are iterating over.

```
def reverse_strings(my_list):
    new_string = ''
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        new_string += my_list[-i-1]
    return new_string
print(reverse_strings(['First', 'Second']))
```